# How can I position my button group to the right of my list item

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have built a Jquery mobile list view. It gets its emlements dynamicaly (I have hard coded one so you can see):

```
<ul id="tripData" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
  <li class="ui-first-child"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Lads Holiday<p><b> Start Date: 2016-03-03</b></p><p><b> End Date: 2016-03-03</b></p><input type="hidden" value="15"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I have built a Jquery mobile button group:

```
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
      </div>
```

What I would like to know is: Where does this button group need to go, and what styles do i need to add,  in order for the result to look like this for each element in the list:

[image: Button group layout]

Answer (score 0):

```
add id="mybtn" to the line below
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="mybtn">
and add this code yo your css
.mybtn{
position: absolute;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
}
```

```css
.mybtn{
  position: absolute;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tripData" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
  <li class="ui-first-child"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Lads Holiday<p><b> Start Date: 2016-03-03</b></p><p><b> End Date: 2016-03-03</b></p><input type="hidden" value="15"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="mybtn">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some CSS Styles using CSS Flexbox, like:

```css
.content-holder {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

div[data-role="controlgroup"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

div[data-role="controlgroup"] a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: none;
}

div[data-role="controlgroup"] a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

div[data-role="controlgroup"] a:first-child {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-holder">
<ul id="tripData" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
  <li class="ui-first-child"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Lads Holiday<p><b> Start Date: 2016-03-03</b></p><p><b> End Date: 2016-03-03</b></p><input type="hidden" value="15"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">Edit</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: My List items are dynamically added into the un-ordered list. I may have 100+ items in the un-ordered list. Where do I put the control group within the un-ordered list?

Comment: @Kōdonomusō-ka Add the unordered list after the end of all the content.